# re-installing Squid proxy

Tags: software-installation, proxy, squid

I have installed squid proxy in my Ubuntu system. Something went wrong in the configuration file. So i need to re-install squid.

1. What is the command to remove squid ?
2. What is the command to install squid again ?
3. How can i configure squid to allow only certain ip to access
   Facebook ?

Comment: there are few lines in the squid.conf file which i cant understand the purpose the codes......>acl MP3 urlpath_regex \.[mM][pP][3]
>acl ZIP urlpath_regex \.[zZ][iI][pP]
>acl MP4 urlpath_regex \.[Mm][pP][4]
>acl MPEG urlpath_regex \.[mM][pP][eE][gG]
>acl BAT urlpath_regex \.[bB][aA][tT]
>acl RAR urlpath_regex \.[rR][aA][rR]
>acl exe  urlpath_regex \.[eE][xX][eE]
>acl torrent urlpath_regex \.[tT][oO][rR][rR][eE][nN][tT]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove squid, and all configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge squid
```

To then install squid

```
sudo apt-get install squid
```

When editing system configuration files, I highly suggest you first back up the original.

```
sudo cp /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/suid.conf.orig
```

When editing files, do not delete anything, use comments

```
#Original line(s)
#Date / reason for edit(s)
New line(s) with edit(s)
```

Your question about the squid conf file should be separate. As a hint, google search regular expressions.